# Does Lorentz transformation apply to a non-inertial frame? Why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

> Two space travellers, S1 and S2, head away from a point in an inertial frame S. The first travels along the trajectory $x = ct/4$ and the second along $x = \beta t^2$. Sketch their
>   trajectories on a spacetime diagram and determine the time in S when their paths
>   cross. How much has each traveller aged at the instant when they cross? Who has
>   aged the most?

I know how to solve the problem. Assuming LT applies to S2, the proper time of S2 $\Delta \tau_2=\int_0^{t_0}\frac t\gamma dt $ which turns out that S1 will age more than S2. But I have multiple problems.

1. Why is LT applicable in this case? My tutor said for a so-called infinitesimal change, everything becomes linear. I just found this quite ambiguous. But when I looked at [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) on wiki, it is indeed an integral.
2. Is it true that when the worldline connecting two event points is a straight line, the proper time interval is the longest? Why?
3. Is it necessary to account for the time dialtion by general relativity as well?

Answer (score 2):

(1) When the rate of change is constant, we can use constant differences, e.g.,

$$c\,\Delta t' = \gamma(c\,\Delta t - \frac{v}{c}\,\Delta x)$$

where $\gamma$ and $v$ are constants.  In the case that $v = v(t)$ is changing with (coordinate) time, we use the differential form of the Lorentz transformation, e.g.,

$$c\,dt' = \gamma(v)(c\,dt - \frac{v(t)}{c}\,dx)$$

and then integrate as needed.

(2) You haven't done your basic research if you have to ask this

(3) GR is not needed for accelerated reference frames in flat spacetime.